# get calendar events for one day into android app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I want to know how can i get an event from the calendar of  a specific date  I just wanna read the events of the selected day ?

this way read all calendar events:

```
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    String title = null;
    long eventID = 0;
    long beginVal = 0;    

    // Get the field values
    eventID = cur.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX);
    beginVal = cur.getLong(PROJECTION_BEGIN_INDEX);
    title = cur.getString(PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX);

    // Do something with the values. 
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Event:  " + title); 
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(beginVal);  
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Date: " + formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));    
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use a [selection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) in your query to filter events by their start date. For example.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2014, Calendar.MAY, 14, 0, 0, 0);
long startDay = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.set(2014, Calendar.MAY, 14, 23, 59, 59);
long endDay = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

String[] projection = new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART };
String selection = CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= ? AND " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + "<= ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { Long.toString(startDay), Long.toString(endDay) }; 

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

Comment: ok but how to call the events on 14 may.. i have mess understanding of this how to show the event into app textView?

Comment: @kura Sorry, but I didn't understand your comment. Didn't you want to get the events for a single day?

Comment: Use CalendarContract.Instances instead if you want to also get the events that are recurring without the hassle of fetching all the events and check if it's recurring on this day or not